Chinese novel in the rebirth genre, where the female lead is kidnapped while pregnant and later travels years into the past
I'm looking to identify this Chinese novel in the rebirth genre. The female lead is kidnapped while pregnant. Her kidnappers call her husband for ransom, but a woman picks up the phone instead and tells her that her husband was shopping with her for baby items and he wasn't going to come save her. The woman then tells her that the baby is not for her husband. Later, she dies at the hands of the kidnappers, and her baby dies too. She subsequently wakes up and finds she has gone years into the past.

What happened after the rebirth?  The pregnant-kidnapping-death is only the beginning, right?
